# Linux mapping virtual memory range to existing virtual memory range?

Tags: c, linux, shared-memory, mmap, virtual-memory

In Linux, is there a way (in user space) to map a virtual address range to the physical pages that back an existing virtual address range?  The mmap() function only allows one to map files or "new" physical pages.  I need to be able to do something like this:

```
int* addr1 = malloc(SIZE);
int* addr2 = 0x60000;      // Assume nothing is allocated here
fancy_map_function(addr1, addr2, SIZE);
assert(*addr1 == *addr2);  // Should succeed
assert(addr1 != addr2);    // Should succeed
```

Comment: Is there a longer and deeper reason behind this? I can mmap(2) an MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_FIXED space at 0x600000 and then do `addr1 = addr2` to obtain almost what you want. Perhaps you have a chance with `shm_open(3)` - but I have a hunch you want something for which there is a more beautiful solution.

Comment: Yes, there's a longer and deeper reason behind this.  Otherwise, you'd be right. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was curious so I tested the shared memory idea suggested in question comments, and it seems to work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define SIZE 256
int main (int argc, char ** argv) {
  int fd;
  int *addr1, *addr2;

  fd = shm_open("/example_shm", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
  ftruncate( fd, SIZE);
  addr1 = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
  addr2 = mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

  printf("addr1 = %p addr2 = %p\n", addr1, addr2);
  *addr1 = 0x12345678;
  assert(*addr1 == *addr2);  // Should succeed
  assert(addr1 != addr2);    // Should succeed

  return 0;
}
```

(Obviously real code will want to check the return value of the syscalls for errors and clean up after itself)

Comment: This actually is closest to what I need. Using shm_open is something I hadn't thought of.

Comment: It was actually "I Give Crap Answers" idea - I found it intriguing enough to try.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the fd for the file mapped at `addr1`, you can simply [`mmap`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) it again at `addr2`.

Otherwise, the Linux-specific [`remap_file_pages`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/remap_file_pages.2.html) can modify the virtual address ⇆ file offset translation within a single VMA, with page-sized granularity, including mapping the same file offset to multiple addresses.

Comment: The remap_file_pages function doesn't look quite right because the original memory is not from a file.  It's anonymous mmap'ed memory.  Still, I gave it a shot and it doesn't seem to work.  After calling this, if I dereference addr2, I get a SIGSEGV. :(

Comment: @boiler96: Yeah, it'll only work on mapped files, not anonymous memory.  You should have checked the return value before dereferencing `addr2` — it probably said `-1`, `errno=EINVAL`.

Comment: Actually, it returned 0, which is very odd.  I would have expected a -1 return code as well.  Anyway, thanks for the thought.

Answer (score -1):

Open `/proc/self/mem` and `mmap` the range of virtual addresses you need from it.

Comment: I get `ENODEV` when I try to `open("/proc/self/mem, O_RDWR)`.  If I `open("/proc/self/mem", O_RDONLY)`, the subsequent `mmap(0, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, addr1)` results in `ENODEV`.  (Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64)

Comment: I believe only a `ptrace()` parent is allowed to use `/proc/<pid>/mem`.  ISTR a discussion where it was determined that this is probably an unnecessary limitation, remaining only for historical reasons.

Comment: Yes, I just tried this too, and it doesn't work.  The mmap returns ENODEV.  In a cruise through the latest kernel code I have (2.6.36), the mmap file operation is not mapped to a handler for the /proc/<pid>|self/mem stuff.  Sadness.